# MERN app deployed on heroku not showing images

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

i have a mern project deployed on heroku with all functionality working except images not appearing.
Here's the project directory:

```
app
  -client
  -server
    -public
      -assets
        -*all images*
```

here's the helmet csp policy with HOST_URL being my website url in the server/index.js file

```
app.use(
    helmet({
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
          defaultSrc: ["'self'", 'HOST_URL'],
          blockAllMixedContent: [],
          fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
          frameAncestors: ["'self'", 'https://accounts.google.com/'],
          frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://accounts.google.com/'],
          imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:', 'HOST_URL'],
          objectSrc: ["'self'", 'blob:'],
          mediaSrc: ["'self'", 'blob:', 'data:','HOST_URL'],
          scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://apis.google.com'],
          scriptSrcAttr: ["'none'"],
          styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
          connectSrc: ["'self'", 'HOST_URL']
        },
      },
    })
  );
```

I have a 'Friend' component that shows a user with their profile picture with userPicturePath being the image name (jpeg or png) located in the client/components/Friend.js folder

```
<Friend
          friendId={postUserId}
          name={name}
          subtitle={location}
          userPicturePath={`HOST_URL/server/public/assets/${userPicturePath}`}
        />
```

I tried using a relative path too: /server/public/assets/image.jpeg

Here's a shot of the site. User profile pics and user image posts should appear.
[image]